# Unexpected end to json input (dash app in python)

Tags: python, json, plotly-dash

I am trying to create a dash app with Python to visualize 2D images; in order to load them faster, I did serialization of numpy arrays (required in json format) (example using json serialization: https://dash.plotly.com/sharing-data-between-callbacks).
The problem is that when I run the app, I get an error saying "Unexpected end to json input".
I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Comment: Hi, can you add some piece of code so that people can try to help you in a more efficient way?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question appears to be missing information necessary to determine the source of your issue. Please include a [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in which all of the necessary information is present so that it can be easily and efficiently tested.

Comment: Hi, thanks for actually replying. The problem was size limit since I wanted to serialize image volume of the shape (139, 512, 512). When I try to serialize image of shape (50, 50, 50) or even bigger, it works fine.